# Motivation behind definition of bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

In the definition of a bounded linear operator ($T:S \subset X \rightarrow Y $): $ \exists C \lt \infty \, s.t.     \forall x \in  S,  \|T(x)\| \le C\|x\| $, (where X,Y are Normed spaces, S- bounded subset), what is the reason to make the definition dependent on $\|x\|$.

We could have found an upper bound just by scanning the entire range of the operator acting on $S$ (i.e. scanning $T(S)$). (By definition, bounded operator maps bounded set to a bounded set, so $T(S)$ is bounded)

i.e., why this definition is not adopted:
$\exists C \lt \infty \, s.t. \,   \forall x \in  S,  \|T(x)\| \le C $.

Comment: Because your second definition is too strong. Your definition isn't equivalent to first defintion if that's what you are wondering

Comment: The second definition is only satisfied by the 0 operator.

Comment: @user160738 , I am sorry, I thought they were equivalent, this was my thought: since S is bounded, $\exists c \lt \infty, \, s.t. \forall x \in S, \, ||x|| \lt c.$ Then I replace ||x|| in the first definition by this c, leading to the second definition.

Comment: @user3108388 And how do you show that first definition implies second one? Thats the real problem. $\|T(x)\|$ does not have to be bounded for first definition to hold. Consider for example identity operator, $I(x)=x$ for all $x$. This is not bounded according to your second definition as long as the ambient space $X$ is not bounded.

Comment: @user3108388 if the set $S$ is bounded then, by your reasoning, the definitions are equivalent. However, this case is rather impractical: you typically want that a linear operator is defined on a subSPACE and not a subSET of a vector space - otherwise, you will have problems to define linearity. Subspaces (which are not equal to $\{0\}$) are never bounded!

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now: I was restricting my attention to bounded sets. (Also mixing up with the definition of bounded functions). So f(x) = x is unbounded linear function but a bounded linear operator. Whereas except for the f(x) = 0 function, there is no other bounded linear function that is also a bounded linear operator.

Comment: @user3108388 correct :)